# Google Storage signed URL: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-bucket

I have a python script that is responsible to sign images url to 150 days (v2) with gcs.
My problem is the url works just fine but after 4 days when I try to enter the image I get

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method

Comment: Can you please update your post sharing your script? Have you tried removing the content type while creating the signed URL as suggested [here?](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1976#issuecomment-278762945) Are you using PUT or POST? changing it could help as in [this post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1976#issuecomment-749231121). Finally, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422663/17544309).

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm also encountering the same error, generating a signature that should last for years but also expires after a few days.. can't pinpoint how many days that is exactly..

Comment: No, It just stopped somehow