# How do I upload a file into google cloud storage using HTML forms?

Tags: typescript, forms, google-cloud-storage, hmacsha256

I want to upload a file directly to a google cloud storage bucket from client side using HTML forms.

I tried the steps given at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-forms

I created a policy document in the same template given in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document

```
{"expiration": "2020-06-16T11:11:11Z",
 "conditions": [
  ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
  {"bucket": "travel-maps"},
  {"success_action_redirect": "http://www.example.com/success_notification.html"},
  ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"],
  ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000],
  {"x-goog-algorithm": "GOOG4-RSA-SHA256"},
  {"x-goog-credential": "example_account@example_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/20191102/us-central1/storage/goog4_request"},
  {"x-goog-date": "20191102T043530Z"}
  ]
}
```

I'm using the HMAC-SHA256 signing algorithm to achieve my goal.

I've used the crypto-js library and followed the above psuedo-code to create my signing key.

I get this error message when I try to upload ->

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>eyJleHBpcmF0a...</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with my implementation of the below psuedo-code. I verified the signing_key with another HMAC encryption-decrytion services online.

```
key_date = HMAC-SHA256("PREFIX" + HMAC_KEY_SECRET, "DATE")
key_region = HMAC-SHA256(key_date, "LOCATION")
key_service = HMAC-SHA256(key_region, "SERVICE")
signing_key = HMAC-SHA256(key_service, "REQUEST_TYPE")
```

below is my implementation

```
    let key_date = crypto.HmacSHA256("20221207","GOOG4" + key);
    let key_region = crypto.HmacSHA256("asia-south2",key_date);
    let key_service = crypto.HmacSHA256("storage",key_region);
    let signing_key = crypto.HmacSHA256("goog4_request",key_service);

  
    let encoded_policy = btoa((JSON.stringify(this.PolicyDocument)));

    let MessageDigest = crypto.HmacSHA256(encoded_policy,signing_key);

    this.signature=MessageDigest.toString();
```

Comment: 1) Show the entire implementation. 2) The `<StringToSign>` shows the string to sign, compare that with the string to sign your implementation created. Your pseudo-code does not come close to creating a valid request based on the details in your question. I think you are missing the V4 signing process. 3) Show the request with the redacted authorization but enough to determine that it looks correct. 4) Why are you using HMAC instead of Google OAuth? Hint, use Google OAuth. More straightforward, with fewer restrictions, HMAC keys are legacy, etc. 5) Never expose the keys in the client browser.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Content-type` as mentioned in this [github thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1976#issuecomment-278762945) or change `Content-type` to `text/csv` or `text/plain`

Also check HTTP method also matching as mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1976#issuecomment-749231121).

For more information check this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422663/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19890062/18265570)